# Pass additional per-instance variable to matrix job

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm running GitLab-CE 16.6.0 (Free, Self-hosted).

I would like to create a pipeline with multiple similar jobs that differ only in a tuple of two variables (e.g. `(image, myvar)`):

| job | image | myvar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `debian:testing` | "x" |
| 2 | `debian:stable` | "y" |
| 3 | `debian:oldstable` | "z" |

So my first attempt is to create a pipeline like so:

```yaml
# the common stuff
.base:
  script:
    - cat /etc/debian_version
    - echo $myvar
     
testing:
  extends: .base
  image: debian:testing
  variables:
    myvar: "x"
stable:
  extends: .base
  image: debian:stable
  variables:
    myvar: "y"
oldstable:
  extends: .base
  image: debian:oldstable
  variables:
    myvar: "z"
```

This works, but it has an awful lot of code duplication (adding a new job in the same vein requires me to write 5 lines)

Using `parallel:matrix`, I could simplify this pipeline a lot:

```yaml
debian:
  extends: base
  image: debian:${debversion}
  parallel:
    matrix:
      debversion:
        - testing
        - stable
        - oldstable
```

That is cool, as adding a new job only requires me to add a single entry to the `debversion` array.

However, while doing so I've lost the possibility to set the `myvar` variable to a job-specific value.

Luckily we can create more-dimensional matrices:

```yaml
debian:
  extends: .base
  image: debian:${debversion}
  parallel:
    matrix:
      debversion:
        - testing
        - stable
        - oldstable
      myvar:
        - x
        - y
        - z
```

Unfortunately this now gives me 3*3=9 jobs (`(testing, x), (testing, y), (testing, z), (stable, x), (stable, y), (stable, z), (oldstable, x), (oldstable, y), (oldstable, z)`) rather than the desired 3 jobs (`(testing, x), (stable, y), (oldstable, z)`).

Things are further complicated by the fact, that this is a shared pipeline definition that my users are supposed to tweak to their own needs (e.g. having different sets of `(debversion, myvar)` tuples)

So:

- I'd rather not litter my `script` with code like:

  ```
  - [ "${debver}" != "testing"] || myvar="x"
  - [ "${debver}" != "stable"] || myvar="y"
  - [ "${debver}" != "oldstable"] || myvar="z"
  ```

  as this would move the variable assignments from declarative variables section to the actual code
- I cannot use dynamic child pipelines, as I need to collect the artifacts in the next stage and the "Free" GitLab-CE does not allow this
- I need to select a Docker image (via `image`), so I (think I) cannot use a single variable that packs two values (e.g. `testing:x`) and then split that into multiple values in the `script` section

Is there a way to achieve passing tuples of variables to jobs (in some terse form)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form each matrix like this

```
job:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - debversion: testing
        myvar: x
      - debversion: stable
        myvar: y
      - debversion: oldstable
        myvar: z
  image: "debian:$debversion"
```

You could also use `rules:variables:` if you wanted, though that would be a bit more verbose.